# Abstract algebra true or false answer check

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Sorry about the giant picture file, but typing up this many questions on Latex would take forever. My attempts are below, I am fairly sure 16+ are right

My answers:
-1T-
-2T-
-3F-
-4F-
-5T-
-6F-
-7F-
-8F-
-9T-
-10T-
-11F - order m-1 right?-
-12F-
-13T-
-14F-
-15T-
-16T-
-17F-
-18F-
-19T-
-20T-\
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure the number you have right is $14$ (maybe $\pm 1$).

Since it's a true/false, I can't in good faith just tell you which ones you got wrong because you're liable to just change the answer. It's nothing personal, it's just a thing. So I will tell you $9$ of the $14$ which you got right, so you only have to review about half of them.

Definitely correct:
$$ 1\qquad 2\qquad 8\qquad 9 \qquad 11^*\qquad 13 \qquad 14\qquad 15\qquad 20$$

Possibly incorrect (5+, probably 6)
$$ 3-7\qquad 10\qquad 12\qquad 16-19 $$

I marked $11$ because you asked a more specific question about it. You wrote the right answer, but the reason you gave is not correct. I think you were thinking of Fermat's little theorem, but you have to be careful: the ambient group in that context that is $(\Bbb Z/p, *)$, which has only $p-1$ elements; that's why the $p-1$ is showing up there.

Comment: @daw: First, I specifically describe in my post the reason I gave a limited amount of information, and I would appreciate it if you would respect that. Second, I would ask you to read the last paragraph of my post again about #11.

Comment: Is 8F because we can have k* the zero vector and have 0? Thank you for your time Eric

Comment: @Katie: Yes, that is the only obstruction. I mean, if you tack on "…except $\{0\}$" then the answer becomes true instead.

Comment: @daw No, the information does apply to XI.  It's the only answer that the OP attached any reasoning to.